# Positioning text at arbitrary positions on a GUI

Tags: python, graphics

I am building a standard radar screen and need to annotate the directions and distances on the rose, at arbitrary positions on the screen. I started with guizero, then pysimplegui and arcade and pygame but have not succeeded in finding a solution to my needs. The text needs to be placed at the end of each direction radial, all around the rose for example. I've tried Googling extensively for a solution, to no avail. I'm a Python newbie but an experienced programmer.

Can someone point me to a solution or post one here?

Comment: Maybe you can draw a text on a canvas, but what is a "rose" how it defined in a radar screen ?

Comment: I'm using rose in the sense of a compass rose - the screen and all its markings with range circles and radials... :)

Comment: Can you share expected image?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "ready-made" solution for your task so you need to build it from scratch. You can use whatever graphics engine you like (`guizero`, `pysimplegui`, `pygame` etc.) and calculate all the directions and distances yourself.
You can start with simple example written with `arcade` lib and then add trigonometry calculations:

```
import arcade

WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 400
RADIUS_MAX = 180
COLOR = arcade.color.WHITE
FONT_SIZE = 12

arcade.open_window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 'Radar')
arcade.start_render()
arcade.draw_circle_outline(center_x=WIDTH/2, center_y=HEIGHT/2, radius=RADIUS_MAX/3, color=COLOR)
arcade.draw_circle_outline(center_x=WIDTH/2, center_y=HEIGHT/2, radius=RADIUS_MAX/3*2, color=COLOR)
arcade.draw_circle_outline(center_x=WIDTH/2, center_y=HEIGHT/2, radius=RADIUS_MAX, color=COLOR)
arcade.draw_line(start_x=WIDTH/2-RADIUS_MAX, start_y=HEIGHT/2, end_x=WIDTH/2+RADIUS_MAX, end_y=HEIGHT/2, color=COLOR)
arcade.draw_line(start_x=WIDTH/2, start_y=HEIGHT/2-RADIUS_MAX, end_x=WIDTH/2, end_y=HEIGHT/2+RADIUS_MAX, color=COLOR)
arcade.draw_text(text='0', start_x=WIDTH/2, start_y=HEIGHT/2+RADIUS_MAX, anchor_x='center', font_size=FONT_SIZE)
arcade.draw_text(text='90', start_x=WIDTH/2+RADIUS_MAX, start_y=HEIGHT/2-FONT_SIZE/2, font_size=FONT_SIZE)
arcade.draw_text(text='180', start_x=WIDTH/2, start_y=HEIGHT/2-RADIUS_MAX-FONT_SIZE, anchor_x='center', font_size=FONT_SIZE)
arcade.draw_text(text='270', start_x=WIDTH/2-RADIUS_MAX, start_y=HEIGHT/2-FONT_SIZE/2, anchor_x='right', font_size=FONT_SIZE)
arcade.finish_render()
arcade.run()
```

Output:

[image: Radar]

Comment: Thank you. That was easy! :)

Is there also a way to rotate the timebase around the rose, without the timebase overwriting the rose? Does Arcade or any other method support frame buffers?